# Powershell transfer of data from Oracle Adapter to Bulk Copy Adapter

Tags: powershell, oledb, sqlbulkcopy, dataadapter

In the Powershell code below to copy data from Oracle to SQL Server, is there a way to get the data from the Oledb adapter ($da)to the Bulk Copy object ($bcp) without filling the data table ($dt)? Can Powershell pipe the data to SQL server more efficiently, eg .instead of copy the data to the data table, read from $da to $bcp in a more direct manner?

```
$con = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection($constr)            
$con.open()            
$cmd = New-Object system.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($qry,$con)            
$cmd.CommandTimeout = '0'            
$da = New-Object system.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter($cmd)            
$dt = New-Object system.Data.datatable            
[void]$da.fill($dt) 
$bcp = new-object system.data.sqlclient.Sqlbulkcopy("server=$server;database=$database;trusted_connection=true");
$bcp.DestinationTableName=$tableName;
$bcp.BulkCopyTimeout='0'
$bcp.BatchSize=75000
$bcp.WriteToServer($dt);
```

I'm looking for speed here. Linked server takes 2 min 30, SSIS takes about 30 sec, and this takes about 20 sec. So I'm wondering if this could be tuned any more. (75K row fetch size is the sweet spot for this oracle connection, so i just set the Bulk copy at the same size). (I'm not stuck on bcp)

Update:

I took mike's advice from the comments below and removed the $dt from the equation

```
Function VAN-ELF () {
        param ( 
                [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [string]$tns, 
                [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$userName, 
                [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$password, 
                [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][int]$fetchSize, 
                [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$sql, 
                [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$sqlServer,
                [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$sqlTable, 
                [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$sqlDb
            )

    try
        {
            $con = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=$tns;User Id=$userName;Password=$password;FetchSize=$fetchSize" ) ;           
            $con.open();            
            $cmd = New-Object system.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($sql,$con);           
            $cmd.CommandTimeout = '0';            
            $da = New-Object system.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter($cmd);  
            $bcp = new-object system.data.sqlclient.Sqlbulkcopy("server=$sqlServer;database=$sqlDb;trusted_connection=true");
            $bcp.DestinationTableName=$sqlTable;
            $bcp.BulkCopyTimeout='0'   
            $bcp.WriteToServer($cmd.ExecuteReader()); 
        }
    catch
        {
            Write-Error ($_.Exception.ToString())
        }
    finally
        {
            if ($con.State -eq 'Open') { $con.close() }
        }

}
```

This shaved a few more seconds off the run time.

Comment: You could try using ExecuteReader on the OleDbCommand to get a Datareader, and passing that to SQLBulkCopy instead of the datatable.  That would eliminate the "pull all the rows down to my box" step.

Comment: I updated the question with your suggestion. Thanks! Is there a danger of crashing the SQL server if the dataset you are trying to move is too large? I assumed that BCP worked in batches like most other things. My DBA is concerned that a large query could potentially eat all the memory on the server. Is that a possibility and how do you mitigate that?

Comment: The query is going to run on the SQL server either way.  The difference is whether you make an object locally with the results or if you "stream" the results from one to the other.  You won't use much local memory, but it shoudn't change the behavior on the SQL Server.